# convert array to desired array

Tags: php, arrays

This is the First Array:

```
Array
(
    [6] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 5
)
```

Second Array:

```
Array
(
    [9] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [10] => 0
)
```

Desired Output Array:

```
Array
(
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 5
)
```

Simply I want to array to sort reverse but with the first array value. I have tried `array_reverse` but it only short the array in reverse and **misplace** the value of it.

Note: the desired array key is the previous 12 month

I have looked the suggested sort array technique but it didn't help

Comment: have a look at this functions, `asort()`,`arsort()`,`ksort()`,`krsort()` ...

Comment: and look at `array_merge`

Comment: why should `10` key go first?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have get the previous 12 month as a key and then reverse it to display in the chart. Current month place at the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check working demo here: https://eval.in/856000

```
<?php 
$array1 = array(6 => 1,
    8 => 1,
    9 => 5);

$array2 = array(9 => 0,
    8 => 0,
    7 => 0,
    6 => 0,
    5 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    12 => 0,
    11 => 0,
    10 => 0);
$mergedArray =[];

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {

    if (array_key_exists($key, $array1)) {      
        if ($array1[$key] > $array2[$key]) {
          $mergedArray[$key] = $array1[$key];
        }
        else {
          $mergedArray[$key] = $array2[$key];
        }
    }
    else {
        $mergedArray[$key] = $array2[$key];
    }
}

print_r(array_reverse($mergedArray,true));

 ?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you've got an answer already but since your goal is related to months I'd like to offer this up:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $month = date('n', strtotime($i . ' month'));
    $merged[$month] = isset($array1[$month]) ? $array1[$month] : $array2[$month];
}
```

I'm just iterating over the numeric representation of the next 12 months and building the array from there - prioritizing values from `$array1`.  If `$array2` is only used for the array keys and always full of of a default value (0s), you don't even need it and you could possibly do something like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $month = date('n', strtotime($i . ' month'));
    $merged[$month] = isset($array1[$month]) ? $array1[$month] : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop the arrays. A simple one liner is all that is needed.

```
$array1 = array(6 => 1,
8 => 1,
9 => 5);

$array2 = array(9 => 0,
8 => 0,
7 => 0,
6 => 0,
5 => 0,
4 => 0,
3 => 0,
2 => 0,
1 => 0,
12 => 0,
11 => 0,
10 => 0);


$res = array_reverse(array_replace($array2, $array1),true);

Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/Xpc26

Array_replace will replace values from array1 in array2.

Answer (score 1):

As per your current input arrays that you have provided, the simplest solution would be as follow:

Reversed the second array by preserving the keys. [Read more about    array_reverse here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Replace reversed array with the first input array whose keys values you want to replace.[Read more about array_replace here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
$reversedArray = array_reverse($b,1); 
$result = array_replace($reversedArray,$a); 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as my answer?

Comment: Yes, it is same, but I think we have posted simultaneously. when I have posted my answer your answer was not there.